# Using ERT in LyX

Tags: tables, beamer, horizontal-alignment, lyx

Using LyX to create a Beamer presentation I used the TeX button to insert some ERT:

```
\begin{table}\caption{Regression table\label{tab1}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l r l r l r l}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 3}\\
\hline
\hline
Variable 1 & 12.758 & * &  13.822 & *** & 2.123 & *\\
\hline
\textit{*p < 0.05, ** p < 0.01, *** p < 0.001}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I am using the beamer conference template. It reads the code fine but on the slide the table is 50 times too big. Is there a way to adjust the table size to put it in correct proportion?

Comment: I hope you are referring to this [ERT](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/ERT#what) for people like me who have no experience with Lyx

Comment: @texenthusiast Yep, that is right.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Regression table\label{tab1}}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{l r l r l r l}\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 3}\\\hline\hline
Variable 1 & 12.758 & * &  13.822 & *** & 2.123 & *\\\hline
\textit{*p < 0.05, ** p < 0.01, *** p < 0.001}
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

which needs package `graphicx`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting the error "(job aborted, no legal \end found)". I have included the `graphicx` package in the preamble and I also have, `booktabs array [justification=centering]{caption}`. No error if I compile without your code.

Comment: send me your lyx file: herbert at dante.de